Android AES Large-File Encryption/Decryption Failed with Out Of Memory
I'm trying to encrypt large files in Android with AES but failed with an error of out of memory.
Here's the code I'm using:
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.documentfile.provider.DocumentFile
import timber.log.Timber
import java.io.IOException
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream
import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

suspend fun encryptFile(
    context: Context,
    file: DocumentFile,
    secretByte: ByteArray,
    iv: ByteArray
) {
    try {
        val bufferSize = 1024 * 1024
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(secretByte, "AES")

        val encryptedFileUri = createEncryptedFileUri(file)
            ?: throw IOException("Failed to create URI for encrypted file")
        
        context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(encryptedFileUri)?.use { outputStream ->


            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(file.uri)?.use { inputStream ->
                val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                var bytesRead: Int

                val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
                val gcmSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
                cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, gcmSpec)

                CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher).use { cipherOutputStream ->
                    while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                        cipherOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                    }
                    cipherOutputStream.flush()
                }

            } ?: throw IOException("Failed to open input stream for file: ${file.uri}")
        } ?: throw IOException("Failed to open output stream for file: $encryptedFileUri")

        if (!file.delete()) {
            Timber.e("Failed to delete original file: ${file.uri}")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Timber.e("Error during file encryption: ${e.message}")
    }
}

private fun createEncryptedFileUri(file: DocumentFile): Uri? {
    val parentDirectory = file.parentFile ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("No parent directory")
    return parentDirectory.createFile("*/*", file.name + ".aesEncr")?.uri
}

Error I'm getting:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 266338320 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 121MB until OOM, target footprint 166187728, growth limit 268435456
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLAeadCipher.expand(OpenSSLAeadCipher.java:127)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLAeadCipher.updateInternal(OpenSSLAeadCipher.java:300)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineUpdate(OpenSSLCipher.java:332)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:1741)
    at javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream.write(CipherOutputStream.java:158)                                                                                                   
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
Suppressed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 132120608 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 121MB until OOM, target footprint 166188144, growth limit 268435456
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineDoFinal(OpenSSLCipher.java:359)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1957)


AEAD cipher modes like GCM are meant for smallish streams that can fit in memory. If you need to encrypt and decrypt large files you will need to use a non-AEAD mode. For example, CBC mode, together with an HMAC. CBC mode is vulnerable to padding oracle attacks, so learn what those are and how to mitigate them.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk That an implementation stores everything in memory instead of processing it in a stream way is an implementation detail, or not? GCM in general could be implemented it low memory footprint or is there something that prevents this?

@Robert: On decryption, the plaintext is considered untrusted until the authentication tag is verified. This requires processing the entire ciphertext first, then verifying the tag, then releasing the decrypted plaintext. I suppose this is considered a "safer" API design, otherwise, if plaintext were released as soon it were available, decisions might be made based on earlier plaintext that was later found to be tampered with by an attacker. GCM and a few other modes are easy to tamper and really need the extra authentication step. I don't know why the ciphertext is withheld during encryption.

This topic has also been discussed here as it affects not only Android but regular J2SE Java: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71712/744

I'm able to fix this using the below code.
Instead of using CipherOutputStream, use the buffer as independent bytes to encrypt
 fun encryptFile(
        context: Context,
        file: DocumentFile,
        secretByte: ByteArray,
        iv: ByteArray
    ) {
        try {
            val bufferSize = 1024 * 1024
            val encryptedFileUri = createEncryptedFileUri(file)
                ?: throw IOException("Failed to create URI for encrypted file")
    
            context.contentResolver.openInputStream(file.uri).use { inputStream ->
                context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(encryptedFileUri).use { outputStream ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                    var bytesRead: Int
                    while (inputStream!!.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
                        val resultByte = encryptByte(buffer, secretByte, iv = iv)
                        outputStream?.write(resultByte, 0, resultByte.size)
                    }
                }
            }
    
            if (!file.delete()) {
                Timber.e("Failed to delete original file: ${file.uri}")
            }
    
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Timber.e("Error during file encryption: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
    
    
    fun encryptByte(byte: ByteArray, key: ByteArray, iv: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        val gcmSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
        val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, gcmSpec)
        return cipher.doFinal(byte)
    }

